# Enabling Barcode128 in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, barcode, code128

I am trying to use Code128 barcodes in Excel. I installed the Barcode128 font and followed [this tutorial](https://www.exceldemy.com/code-128-barcode-font-for-excel). But I just get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u20Vj.png).

Anyone have experience getting this to work?

- Installed Barcode128 font
- Created a new Excel document
- Added VBA code as CODE128 function
- Entered CODE128 function as a formula connecting a cell with alphanumeric data to a cell intended to house barcode data

Was expecting the two cells to connect such that changing the alphanumeric data in the first cell would change the barcode data in the connected cell. Barcode did not seem to change as I changed the alphanumeric data, and the error shown above appeared.

Comment: Where did you put the CODE128 function?  In what module?

Comment: This post looks as though it would make a barcode label in Word using an Excel data source...  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-barcodes-to-labels-495cf789-c9d9-4ea5-8eb9-7299170d4831

Comment: This post is specific to Excel ...  https://code.adonline.id.au/easily-generate-code-128-barcodes-in-excel/

Comment: The answer to this question will be useful. Excel has changed over the years so posts have gone out of date.

Comment: The `Invalid Name` error means that Excel does not recognise the name of the function. You need to define it as a `Public` function for it to work as I remember it.

Comment: However, this is what Microsoft says about Custom Functions...  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f